# MPMoviePlayerController iPhone 3G & .mov file format

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, 3g, .mov

Just posting a question to the world... My app is currently setup to play video files.  The app is setup to play .mov files and when tested on a 3GS, iPhone 4, and an iPad, it works great.  But when playing on an iPhone 3G, the file does not play.  Is this based on different compression standards that the 3G can't handle?  I liked the .mov extension as it was compressed nicely to stream to the device.  I have now converted the video files to .m4v so it will play on the 3G, but the file is now 3 times the size.  Thanks in advance for any answers I get!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3G doesn't support (in my experience, can't find it in the docs) .mov. Converting to another format is probably the best option. You might try using quicktime to convert to "iPhone (cellular)" as that format will by smaller.

Comment: Late comment, but I believe you are correct in your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

3G shouldn't have differences with format with 3GS, is the 3G running the same OS version as the others? MPMoviePlayerController got changed in between 3.0 and 3.2/4.0 significantly, and you will have to implement it differently for the two versions.

Comment: Yes, the 3G is running 4.2.1.